# Can a USB power surge cause on one port cause damage to another device?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, external-hard-drive

I recently discovered that an external hard drive is giving a "device not recognized" error.  It has been plugged in and in use for several years.

A couple days before realizing that the hard drive will not work, I was working with a usb microcontroller (plugged into the front) and caused a "power surge on hub port" by not wiring things correctly.  The HDD was plugged in (to the back) at that time.  So I am concerned that I might have damaged the USB controller on the HDD.  Unfortunately, I cannot say for sure whether or not the HDD was having problems prior this incident.

Other devices, including mice, keyboard, printer and my breadboard device that caused the surge, communicate fine with the PC.  I've rotated the ports which the devices use, and get the same results:  everything works on any port, except the HDD is not recognized.

So in general, can a USB power surge affect devices on other ports?  In particular, does it sound as though the HDD is the problem?  What could possibly be wrong on the PC side, and how can I investigate those possibilities?

Working on Lenovo Thinkcentre, Windows XP.

Thanks!

Comment: It would depend on the motherboard, the more expensive ones have an electronic fuse for each port to help prevent a single device damaging others. Still, I would expect the front and back ports to have some isolation from each other since they would normally be on two different USB host controllers.

Comment: I have a HDD that sometimes goes off line, like that.  Power cycling (the drive) brings it back on line.

Comment: What did you do exactly with your microcontroller board? Did it have an external power supply that got "injected" into the USB plug by mistake?

Comment: It would be very unlikely that a problem with the from USB port would affect a device connected to one of the back USB ports. They usually use different host controllers. I would try using the HDD on a different system and using a different USB cable.

Comment: I have a 9V battery and a 5V regulator, but I think I just shorted the USB power and ground which would draw to much current and cause the surge on the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unlikely that you would have caused such damage. If you have, I would expect other USB devices to fail to work as well so why not try some other devices.

It could be coincidence that the drive has chosen this time to fail. They do fail fairly regularly in my experience.

You can get fairly cheap adapters designed to copy drives that allow raw drives to be connected to USB so you could also remove the actual HD from the USB enclosure and try one of those to make sure the HD itself isn't dead.

Comment: Thanks to everyone.  I think I needed some voices of calm and reassurance.  Power resets did the trick for me.